# How to handle 404 bad request in ASP.NET core Web API 6.0 in ExceptionHandlerMiddleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ExceptionHandlerMiddleware class:

```
public class ExceptionHandlingMiddleware {
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ExceptionHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext) {
        try {
            await _next(httpContext);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
        }
    }
    private async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        var response = context.Response;

        var errorResponse = new ErrorResponse {
            Success = false
        };
        switch (exception) {
            case AppException ex:
                if (ex.Message.Contains("Invalid token")) {
                    response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                    errorResponse.Message = ex.Message;
                    break;
                }
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                errorResponse.Message = ex.Message;
                break;
            case KeyNotFoundException ex:
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                errorResponse.Message = ex.Message;
                break;
            default:
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                errorResponse.Message = "Internal Server errors." + exception.Message;
                break;
        }
        var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(errorResponse);
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
}
```

and a controller

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int id, UpdateEmployeeDto employee) {
        if (id != employee.ID) {
            throw new AppException(
                string.Format("id = {0} does not match that of the employee to update id = {1}",
                id, employee.ID));
        }

        await _service.UpdateEmployee(employee);

        return Ok(employee);
    }
```

The tutorial I was following showed to throw an error like so. I get the custom error message in my custom AppException, but it still goes on to return a 500 server error with this message

> "Internal Server errors.The exception handler configured on
> ExceptionHandlerOptions produced a 404 status response. This
> InvalidOperationException containing the original exception was thrown
> since this is often due to a misconfigured ExceptionHandlingPath. If
> the exception handler is expected to return 404 status responses then
> set AllowStatusCode404Response to true.",

Edit: I removed my ErrorController and that seems to have fixed it. Not sure why the docs show creating one before creating the middleware...or maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: 404 is not found. bad request is 400

Comment: So it goes on to make the service call after the error is thrown?

Comment: I tried with your codes and it works well,have you make a break point and debugged?

Comment: Yeah it handles the app exception for a bad request and I get the message in my logs, but it still goes on to return a 500 server response

Comment: It consumes the AppException and throws an InvalidOperationException

Comment: I think you may check if there are any errors caused by the change of the statuecode as the error indicates